# unzip file in /tmp using aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am downloading zip files into /tmp folder, using lambda function in node js, but when i try to decompress the same files, my lambda function stops executing calling decompress.

any ideas how can i handle this ?

this is part of the code:

```
    for (let delivery of products.deliveries) {
        for (let zfile of delivery.files) {
            // console.log({ zip_file });
            var folderName = zfile.fileName.replace(".zip", "");
            var fileNameZip = `/tmp/${zfile.fileName}`;
            
            let exist = await s3.listObjectsV2({ Bucket: someName, Prefix: folderName}).promise();
            
            if (exist.KeyCount) {
                await P.downloadFile(
                    token,
                    fileNameZip,
                    delivery.deliveryId,
                    delivery.files[0].fileId,
                    zfile.fileSize
                );
                await Puller.unzipFile(fileNameZip);
                console.log("THIS HAPPENS")
                await Puller.extractFolder(fileNameZip, `/tmp/${folderName}`);
                console.log("DOES NOT HAPPEN")
            }
```

this is extractFolder

```
    public async extractFolder(fileName: string, folderName: string): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
        console.log(`extracting ${fileName}`);
        console.log(`extracting into folder ${folderName}`);
        await decompress(fileName, folderName);
        console.log('LOG NOT SHOWN')
        return true
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error)
        return false
    }
}
```

note: No error is happening.

Comment: Could you share the logs for the error? Does it happen all the time or just for the subsequent ones?

Comment: The funny part is that there are no errors in the logs. At the moment, my logic works, so I can work with only one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you were unzipping to a directory name that is either:

- Non-existent and the decompress method throws an error because the landing directory does not exists. If this is the case, add a logic to create it if it does not exists.
- Existent and the decompress directory can’t extract the files because of naming collisions, if this is the case then implement a dynamic naming for the directory by appending UUIDs.

Those are the two immediate bugs that could potentially happen on the code you shared. If it does not suffice, please share the contents of decompress function and the logs from CloudWatch.

UPDATE:

- It seems like you were decompressing a fairly huge ZIP file.
- I'm recommending to increase the memory size / ephemeral storage allocated to your Lambda function to a size that will make your Lambda function start functioning
- Your machine is more likely to have a larger memory size than the function itself.

Comment: okay, i am checking now both ways, the content of the decompress function is above, the second function, 
the logs are the next one, please note that i am testing my function locally, 

`
2023-07-06T06:58:18.329Z 6042a77e-f602-4826-a34e-64bca84d7685 INFO Download in progress to /tmp/docdb_xml_bck_202308_025_B.zip (289.4 MB)...
2023-07-06T06:59:55.642Z 6042a77e-f602-4826-a34e-64bca84d7685 INFO Download completed to /tmp/docdb_xml_bck_202308_025_B.zip

`

Comment: 2023-07-06T06:58:18.329Z 6042a77e-f602-4826-a34e-64bca84d7685 INFO Download in progress to /tmp/docdb_xml_bck_202308_025_B.zip (289.4 MB)...
2023-07-06T06:59:55.642Z 6042a77e-f602-4826-a34e-64bca84d7685 INFO Download completed to /tmp/docdb_xml_bck_202308_025_B.zip

Comment: let me note that i did everything in the simple node js app, and everything is working locally but when invoking my lambda function locally i am getting the issues.

Comment: :D @Metotwi8, if this solutions helped you. please don't hesitate to mark it as the answer so the others could solve their similar challenges in the future!